# Fabric2 throws `paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException` during nested SSH to localhost (port 2022) on an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ssh, paramiko, python-fabric-2

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. SSH into an EC2 instance `Node1`.

   - `Public IP` is available for Node1.
   - I am using a `.pem` file to create `Connection` with Node1.
2. From `Node1` ssh into localhost on port 2022: `ssh admin@localhost -p 2022`

   - Now execute a command, while inside localhost.

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
from fabric2 import Connection

jump_host_ip = "A.B.C.D"
user = "root_user"
pem_key = "example.pem"

with Connection(jump_host_ip, user=user, connect_kwargs={"key_filename": pem_key}) as jump_host:
    with Connection('localhost', user='dummy_user', port=2022,
                    connect_kwargs={'password': 'password'}, gateway=jump_host) as local_host:
        local_host.run('ls -la')
```

This code is hosted on another EC2 server. And when executed from the EC2 server it throws the following exception:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

But this `code works` when executed from a local machine `(not from EC2 server)`.

Is it possible EC2 could be blocking the Connection to localhost through `gateway` ?
If yes, what should be the fix for this ?

Comment: @MartinPrikry: When I try this manually from terminal, the ssh is successful. And there is no authentication failure.
1. I do ssh into Node1: ssh user@node1 
2. From Node1 I execute: ssh admin@localhost -p 2022. It asks me for the password. And it works.

In which possible scenario the target server could block the authentication ? Could it be related to the port number (i.e. 2022) ?

Comment: Adding `'look_for_keys': False` to `connect_kwargs` fixed this issue for me.
Thanks @MartinPrikryl for your inputs.